# delete duplicates between two rows Tableau

Tags: python, duplicates, tableau-api

how to delete duplicates between two values and keep the first value only on tableau for each user id ?
for example for a certain user :
| status | date |
| -------- | -------------- |
| success| 1/1/2022|
| fail| 1/2/2022|
| fail| 1/3/2022|
| fail| 1/4/2022|
| success| 1/5/2022|
i want the results to be :

| status | date |
| -------- | -------------- |
| success| 1/1/2022|
| fail| 1/2/2022|
| success| 1/5/2022|
on python it would be like this :

````
edited_data=[]

for key in d:
    
    dup = [True]

    total_len = len(d[key].index)
    for i in range(1, total_len):
        if d[key].iloc[i]['status'] == d[key].iloc[i-1]['status']:
            dup.append(False)
        else:
            dup.append(True)
   edited_data.append(d[key][dup])```
````

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is with the LOOKUP() function. Since this particular problem requires each row to know what came before it, it will be important to make sure your dates are sorted correctly and that the table calculation is computed correctly. Something like this should work:

```
IF LOOKUP(MIN([Status]),-1) = MIN([Status]) THEN "Hide" ELSE "Show" END
```

And then simply hide or exclude the "Hide" rows.

[image: Screenshot of Tableau using above calculation]